# Unexpected results with LAST_VALUE, CURRENT ROW, and NULLs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions, sql-server-2014

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Transfers (
    AddedOn DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,
    NewDeptID INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Transfers
VALUES 
    ('2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987', 19, 36),
    ('2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087', 19, NULL),
    ('2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928', 22, 100),
    ('2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703', 22, NULL),
    ('2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000', 22, 37),
    ('2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000', 22, NULL)
```

For each row, I am trying to get the most recent non-null `NewDeptID` (until that row):

```
SELECT *,
    LAST_VALUE(NewDeptID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY EmpID
        ORDER BY IIF(NewDeptID IS NULL,0,1), AddedOn
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS CurrentDeptID
FROM #Transfers
ORDER BY EmpID, AddedOn
```

If I understand correctly, null values should be excluded because they are the first values in the window -- `IIF(NewDeptID IS NULL,0,1)`.

I would expect the following:

```
AddedOn                        EmpID  NewDeptID  CurrentDeptID
2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987    19     36         36
2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087    19     NULL       36
2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928    22     100        100
2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703    22     NULL       100
2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000    22     37         37
2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    22     NULL       37
```

Instead, the ORDER BY clause within the LAST_VALUE is ignored, and NULL is returned when the current row contains NULL:

```
AddedOn                        EmpID  NewDeptID  CurrentDeptID
2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987    19     36         36
2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087    19     NULL       NULL --
2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928    22     100        100
2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703    22     NULL       NULL --
2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000    22     37         37
2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    22     NULL       NULL --
```

I am getting the same results in SQL Server 2012 and 2014.

Is this a bug in SQL Server, or am I missing something in the window function syntax?

---

Note: If I expand the window to include the entire partition, the NULLs are ignored:

```
SELECT *,
    LAST_VALUE(NewDeptID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY EmpID
        ORDER BY IIF(NewDeptID IS NULL,0,1), AddedOn
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS CurrentDeptID
FROM #Transfers
ORDER BY EmpID, AddedOn
```

Results:

```
AddedOn                        EmpID  NewDeptID  CurrentDeptID
2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987    19     36         36
2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087    19     NULL       36
2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928    22     100        37
2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703    22     NULL       37
2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000    22     37         37
2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    22     NULL       37
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have not understood well, how window functions work. The `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is applied **after** the `ORDER BY IIF...`, so first the rows are ordered (first the ones having `NULL`, then all the rest) and then the `ROWS ...` restriction is applied. So, this is never going to work for your problem.

In detail, the `OVER` clause creates these "windows", according to the `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY`.
So, for example for the row with `AddedOn = '2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000'`, the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` are the row above and itself (the two rows marked with `<------`):

```
AddedOn                        EmpID  IIF()  NewDeptID 

-- partition EmpID = 19
2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087    19     0       NULL       
2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987    19     1        36        

-- partition EmpID = 22
2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703    22     0       NULL  <---
2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    22     0       NULL  <---  this is the LAST_VALUE
2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928    22     1       100       
2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000    22     1        37
```

So, the `CurrentDeptID` column gets these values:

```
AddedOn                        EmpID  IIF()  NewDeptID CurrentDeptID

-- partition EmpID = 19 
2013-12-18 13:02:34.1168087    19     0       NULL     NULL
2013-12-17 17:18:54.3499987    19     1        36       36 

-- partition EmpID = 22
2014-02-05 10:36:36.3645703    22     0       NULL     NULL
2014-02-17 00:00:00.0000000    22     0       NULL     NULL
2014-01-28 11:41:55.8755928    22     1       100      100 
2014-02-16 00:00:00.0000000    22     1        37       37
```

which are then re-ordered for the final result, according to the external `ORDER BY`

---

To work around the problem, you could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *,
    ( SELECT TOP (1) NewDeptID
      FROM #Transfers AS ti
      WHERE ti.EmpID = t.EmpID
        AND ti.NewDeptID IS NOT NULL
        AND ti.AddedOn <= t.AddedOn
      ORDER BY AddedOn DESC
    ) AS CurrentDeptID
FROM #Transfers AS t
ORDER BY EmpID, AddedOn ;
```

Test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/283e6/4)

---

What you are trying to do would actually make sense if nulls could be ignored by the `LAST_VALUE()` function. This can be done with **`IGNORE NULLS`** but unfortuantely this feature has not been yet implemented in SQL-Server. You can see how it would work, in **[Oracle (fiddle-2)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0f5e/7)**:

```
SELECT AddedOn, EmpID, NewDeptID,
    LAST_VALUE(NewDeptID) 
      IGNORE NULLS                                -- check this
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY EmpID
        ORDER BY AddedOn
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS CurrentDeptID
FROM Transfers
ORDER BY EmpID, AddedOn ;
```

---

Another way, with window functions, that works in SQL-Server, is by counting the not-null `NewDeptID` before the current row first. You can test at **[fiddle-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/283e6/16)**:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT AddedOn, EmpID, NewDeptID,
      COUNT(NewDeptID) OVER (
          PARTITION BY EmpID
          ORDER BY AddedOn
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS cnt
    FROM Transfers 
  )
SELECT AddedOn, EmpID, NewDeptID,
    MIN(NewDeptID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, cnt) AS CurrentDeptID
FROM cte
ORDER BY EmpID, AddedOn ;
```

Comment: I don't understand. If the `ORDER BY` is applied first, then the records with null values are first within the partition. When calculating the last value within the partition up to the current row, the result should never be null, unless the value for all previous records in the partition was also null.

Comment: But you said so, *"the records with null values are first within the partition"*. If a row has null, all rows before it have null as well. And when I wrote `ORDER BY`, I meant the `ORDER BY IIF...`, not the external order by.

Comment: Your `IIF()` does not allow that (all rows with not null are placed after all the rows with null). I edited my answer with details on how the windows work.

Comment: So `LAST_VALUE` with `ROWS BETWEEN ... AND CURRENT ROW` will always return the current row's value? As will `FIRST_VALUE` with `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND ... `?

Comment: Yes, thnx. Corrected. (and yes, exactly to the previous question)